# How to dynamically pass Facebook App ID in info.pliost?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-apps, info.plist

I am making an app in which user admin can change the Facebook app id as per him requirement. Now I am receiving this app id from web-service. And I want to pass this app ID in info.plist in FacebookAppID key. So can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't change in application bundle items during run time.

Comment: Thannks for reply. But are you sure for it?

Comment: yes, we can't change in Application bundle during run time. but you can use same appid for multiple application.

Answer (score 0):

We can not change anything in application bundle. We used this to store values at one time.